# What happens if 2 scoiatel players play each other?

Tags: gwent

In the new game from CD Projekt Red, the Scoiatel players can decide who goes first on the first turn.

But if 2 scoiatel players play each other, does one choose? What happens?

Comment: Based on TW3, the powers cancel out, and it goes back to a coin flip to decide. Hopefully someone can confirm this is the case in the standalone as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Scoia'Tael vs. Scoia'Tael match, the faction abilities cancel out and neither player gets to choose who goes first. The game treats both players as having no faction ability at all in this case.

Also note that the ability is not limited to the first turn, the Scoia'Tael player may choose to "Ignore" the ability and use it in a later round, which is often used to make the opponent go first in a round the player would have had to go first (in order to get the last move), or to go first in a round the opponent would have been allowed to go first (in order to play an important card asap), although the latter is very rare.